# Create map in PHP without using Google map API

Tags: php, dictionary

Is there any way to create map in php without using google map API?I need to create a map in a web application without using Google map.IIf so,Please help me.

Comment: Well the first thing you'll need is some mapping data.  Better invest in a theodolite and a sextant!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/), or [bing maps](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx) are quite good too.

Comment: Is it open source??I need it to integrate with php

Comment: OpenStreetMap is open source.